# How to group by multiple excel columns into one list with a header

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

So I have a dataset in Google Sheets (Excel) like the following in two columns

```
Movie1, Jack
Movie1, John
Movie1, Henry
Movie1, Hanson
Movie2, Bill
Movie2, Benny
Movie3, Gary
Movie4, Robert
```

I want to combine these dataset in these two columns and multiple rows into something like this

```
Movie1
Jack
John
Henry
Hanson
=====
Movie2
Bill
Benny
=====
Movie3
Gary
=====
Movie4
Robert
```

This is including the

```
=====
```

as part of the dataset, ideally each entry should be on a separate row there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Google Sheets

- Headings in Column `A`
- Data in `A:B`

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(CHAR(10), Byrow(UNIQUE(A:A), 
 LAMBDA(x, IF(x<>"", JOIN(CHAR(10), {query(A:B, 
 "select B where A contains '"&x&"' label B '"&x&"'");
 "=====" }),)))),CHAR(10)))
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: ,,, nice solution +10 ☺

Comment: Ty.  I'm sure someone will come along with a shorter/simpler  solution :-)